# liquid template `for` loop: how to `continue` to skip an iteration

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I would like to skip an iteration based on a condition.

I'm using liquid templates as part of Jekyll.

I don't see a continue in the docs:

http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/liquid/Liquid/For

```
{% for page in site.pages %}
  {% if page.url == '/index.html' %}
    // Continue here
  {% endif %}
  {{ page.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 24):

You can use the [continue](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/liquid/Liquid/Continue) tag, which works just like a `continue` in any other language. It's documented in a separate section:

```
{% for page in site.pages %}
  {% if page.url == '/index.html' %}
    {% continue %}
  {% endif %}
  {{ page.title }}
{% endfor %}
```